How to align the input text so that it's in the middle of the text box
I thought it would look good if I change the font that is typed into the text box but the letters are not aligned in the middle.
enter image description here
The letters are instead sticking at the top right corner. How do I fix this? (I don't want to center the letters)


#textInput {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: grey;
  height: 20px;
  width: 210px;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: MathGG;
  font-size: 20px;
}
<input id="textInput" type="text">



I tried using
text-align: middle;

but that didn't work.

Have you tried text-align: center ?

I am positive this is a dup somewhere

Without seeing it with the actual font you are using we can't provide an exact solution, but you should be able to do this with padding. For example, if the text is too high in the input simply add some top padding.
Adjusting the line-height might help as well.


#textInput {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: grey;
  height: 20px;
  width: 210px;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: MathGG;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px; /* Adjust this */
  padding-top:5px; /* And this */
}
<input id="textInput" type="text">




How does the line height help?

@Allen because sometimes fonts will render strangely in browsers, especially if the font you're using was not made specifically for the web. Adjusting the line-height may allow you to get the text more centered within the input for that particular font.

The text in the input field is vertically centered by default. You have to consider all letters/characters, not only the ones that don't descend below the baseline. See the example below:


#textInput {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: grey;
  height: 20px;
  width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: MathGG;
  font-size: 20px;
}
<input id="textInput" type="text" value="it is vertically centered: consider *all* letters like g t p b y etc.">



If you only use uppercase letters (which don't have any descenders), you can use different top and bottom padding – you'll have to find out the right values by trial and error. Example (I only used padding-top here):


#textInput {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: grey;
  height: 20px;
  width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top:4px;
}
<input id="textInput" type="text" value="UPPER CASE LETTERS ONLY, WITH TOP PADDING">




I typed ggggg, but it looks a bit weird.

@mrconcerned "ggggg" will look weird in any context...

The line-height property specifies the height of a line.
Normal height property is used to set height of other html elements but to set height of a text line line-height property is used.
To vertically align middle of text the line-height property should be equal to the height of the element.  In this case the line-height and height of textbox should be equal.


#textInput {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 210px;
  font-family: MathGG;
  font-size: 20px;
  /* added below code to understand better */
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  line-height: 50px;
}
<input id="textInput" type="text" value="the quick brown fox " />





I tried using
text-align: middle

It should be text-align: center
See MDN

The thing is I don't want my text to be in the very center of the text input. I want to vertically center it.

@Allen Then you'll want the new align-content
